# How to deselect view after a certain time without freezing activity

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, view

i need some good advice for my code. 
here is what i want to do.

i have an activity that has some views that can be selected by user. assumed that the user selected a view, i want to deselect this view automatically after, let's say, 5 seconds. 
I do this by a thread.

when the user selects the view, i call...

```
Deselector deselect = new Deselector(mp.getDuration(), clickedview);
deselect.start();
```

...in the activity.

the deselector class:

```
class Deselector extends Thread
{
int millis=0;
View view = null;

Deselector(int millis, View view)
{
    this.millis = millis;
    this.view = view ; 
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        this.sleep(millis);
        view.setSelected(false);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

my program crashes and logkitty says

> 12-11 14:29:37.457: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3263): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

how to do it right?

thanks in advance

m.d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `postDelayed()` on a widget or a `Handler`, rather than a background thread, to do work after your proposed delay.

Answer (score 1):

i got it working by doing the following

```
clickedview.postDelayed(new Deselector(clickedview), mp.getDuration());
```

with my deselctor runnable now a bit shorter:

```
class Deselector implements Runnable
{
View view = null;

Deselector(View view)
{
    this.view = view ; 
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        view.setSelected(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```